# Portable builds and CDNs, with next-images and next-fonts

Tags: reactjs, webpack, next.js

I'm trying to make my Next.js builds portable, meaning that I run the build command once and then the site can be deployed to any environment with all the differences being controlled by environment variables. The primary motivation for this is to speed up deploy times when going via QA or staging environments to production.

I also want to uploaded all the static files (mainly js, images and fonts) to S3.

I'm using next-images and next-fonts, the problem is that both of these seem to only allow us to encode the public path of these assets at build time. So if I want to include the CDN prefix in the path, I lose the ability to have portable builds.

Next.js itself allows it's own `assetPrefix` to be set at runtime, so what I do have working as expected is Next-managed assets such as script files.

I've spent hours trying to mess with `__webpack_public_path__` to try and get this working, without any success. Right now, the only viable plan I have is to wrap every single use of static assets with a function that determines the path prefix at runtime. This is going to be a huge amount of work, so i'd prefer not to do it if there's a better way.

Has anyone managed to solve this at the config level, rather than at the application-code level?

Comment: I'm sorry to report that in my current app we do the same thing at the application-code level. We have put a few abstractions in place to centralize the logic of handling an asset prefix, in prevision of the day we either change it or remove it. Unfortunately I don't know a better way to do that.

Comment: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/cdn-support-with-asset-prefix  so this is solved?

Comment: @JoshLin no, I don't think so. The change in 9.5 doesn't impact the issue I've been having